# How to rotate a 3d model horizontally with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am having trouble rotating my 3d man object model horizontally via three.js.

My main confusion is that I dont know if I should to be controlling the camera angle or the object angle in order to achieve this and based on my research, there seemes to be different methods to achieving what I need but I am not sure which method would work with what I implemented so far.

```
<script src="js/three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/OBJLoader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
        <script>

            var scene, camera, renderer , controls, ambientLight, pointLight, textureLoader, map, material, loader;
            var WIDTH  = window.innerWidth;
            var HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
            var SPEED = 0.01;

            function init() {
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                initChris();
                initCamera();
                initRenderer();
                    initControl();
                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            }

            function initCamera() {
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, WIDTH / HEIGHT, 1, 8000);
                    ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xcccccc, 0.4 );
                    pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 0.8 );

                camera.position.set(0, 0, 4000);
                    camera.add( pointLight );
                    scene.add( camera );
                    scene.add( ambientLight );
                camera.lookAt(scene.position);
            }

            function initRenderer() {
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
                renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
                    renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
            }

            function initControl(){

                    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
                    controls.enableZoom  = false;
                    controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.5;
                    controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.5;
                    controls.update();
            }

            function initChris() {
                textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                map = textureLoader.load('img/CHRIS.BMP');
                material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({map: map});
                loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                loader.load( 'obj/CHRIS.OBJ', function ( object ) {
                  object.traverse( function ( node ) {
                    if ( node.isMesh ){
                            node.material = material;
                        }
                  });
                  scene.add( object );
                });
            }

            function render() {
                requestAnimationFrame(render);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }

            init();
            render();

        </script>
```

I also dont know if there is something wrong with my 3d man model because I tried using different models and each model gave me a different rotation angle. For example, the model I am currently working with is showing my 3d man model at birds-eye-view and the rotation pivot is occuring at his feet while if I change the 3d man model taken from three.js example, I get to see the 3d man model at front view and the rotation pivot is centered which is what I am tryin to achieve with the 3d man model that I am working with.

Any help or advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To start, you need a frame of reference. Add `scene.add( new THREE.AxesHelper( 1000 ) );` Also, for now, set `controls.minPolarAngle = 0;` It should then be clear that you need to rotate and/or translate your model. If you are not able to do that, you can edit and clarify your question.

Comment: I added the codes as advised but I dont know what I am looking at to be honest!
I dont know what needs to clarrified?!
I have gone back to the designer who created the 3d man object to compare with the 3d object provided by three.js and compare what is different to try and fix.

Comment: In three.js, the y-axis (green) is up; the xz-plane( red-blue) is parallel to the ground. If your model is not upright, you need to rotate the model so it is.

Comment: How do i rotate the model? Do I use Matrix4? Vector3? OrbitControls?

Comment: `OrbitControls` is for controlling a camera. You can rotate an object by setting its `rotation` property. For example: `object.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2`; I think you need to study some three.js tutorials.

Comment: Using those functions worked for me:
object.rotateX(angle);
object.rotateY(angle);
object.rotateZ(angle);